# How to disable the UI/UX of dragging outside tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I would like to achieve a dragging that would only happen inside a tableView.
Right now, I can able to drag it outside the tableView. I would like it to behave, as if it has a collider in the corners.[image]